# Compartmentalizing loops over a large iteration

Tags: java, performance, optimization, arraylist, nested-loops

The Goal of my question is to enhance the performance of my algorithm by splitting the range of my loop iterations over a large array list.
For example: I have an Array list with a size of about 10 billion entries of long values, the goal I am trying to achieve is to start the loop from 0 to 100 million entries, output the result for the 100 million entries of whatever calculations inside the loop; then begin and 100 million to 200 million doing the previous and outputting the result, then 300-400million,400-500million and so on and so forth.
after I get all the  100 billion/100 million results, then I can sum them up outside of the loop collecting the results from the loop outputs parallel.

I have tried to use a range that might be able to achieve something similar by trying to use a dynamic range shift method but I cant seem to have the logic fully implemented like I would like to.

```
public static void tt4() {
    long essir2 = 0;
    long essir3 = 0;

    List cc = new ArrayList<>();  
    List<Long> range = new ArrayList<>();  

    // break point is a method that returns list values, it was converted to 
    // string because of some concatenations and would be converted back to long here
    for (String ari1 : Breakpoint()) {
        cc.add(Long.valueOf(ari1));
    }  

    // the size of the List is huge about 1 trillion entries at the minimum
    long hy = cc.size() - 1;

    for (long k = 0; k < hy; k++) { 
        long t1 = (long) cc.get((int) k);
        long t2 = (long) cc.get((int) (k + 1)); 

        // My main question: I am trying to iterate the entire list in a dynamic way 
        // which would exclude repeated endpoints on each iteration. 

        range = LongStream.rangeClosed(t1 + 1, t2)
                          .boxed()
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());  

        for (long i : range) {
            // Hard is another method call on the iteration
            // complexcalc is a method as well

            essir2 = complexcalc((int) i, (int) Hard(i)); 
            essir3 += essir2;
        } 
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + essir3);  
}
```

I don't have any errors, I am just looking for a way to enhance performance and time. I can do a million entries in under a second directly, but when I put the size I require it runs forever. The size I'm giving are abstracts to illustrate size magnitudes, I don't want opinions like a 100 billion is not much, if I can do a million under a second, I'm talking massively huge numbers I need to iterate over doing complex tasks and calls, I just need help with the logic I'm trying to achieve if I can.

Comment: I would suggest formatting your code a bit better so it's more readable. Will be easier to spot potentially unoptimized code that way.

Comment: "the size of the List is huge about 1 trillion entries at the minimum" - 1 trillion elements? I don't think so...

Comment: its a value to the power of 15-20. that is >=x^15

Comment: 1 trillion boxed primitives would require you to have at-least 20 terabytes of heap space.

Comment: I also have a method that I can use to split the size into n equal parts, the most I would get for a 100 million size per iteration would be about 50 thousand entries for a 100 million per size. External DBs and wrappers can be used as is the case for these values, but the point is not to. Time and performance with basic libraries is the goal here.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest right off the bat would be to store your `Breakpoint` return value inside a simple array rather then using a `List`. This should improve your execution time significantly:

```
    List<Long> cc = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String ari1 : Breakpoint()) {
        cc.add(Long.valueOf(ari1));
    }
    Long[] ccArray = cc.toArray(new Long[0]);
```

I believe what you're looking for is to split your tasks across multiple threads. You can do this with [ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) *"which simplifies the execution of tasks in asynchronous mode"*.

Note that I am not overly familiar with this whole concept but have experimented with it a bit recently and give you a quick draft of how you could implement this.

I welcome those more experienced with multi-threading to either correct this post or provide additional information in the comments to help improve this answer.

**Runnable Task class**

```
public class CompartmentalizationTask implements Runnable {

    private final ArrayList<Long> cc;
    private final long index;

    public CompartmentalizationTask(ArrayList<Long> list, long index) {

        this.cc = list;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Main.compartmentalize(cc, index);
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
private static ExecutorService exeService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private static List<Future> futureTasks = new ArrayList<>();

public static void tt4() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException 
{
    long essir2 = 0;
    long essir3 = 0;

    ArrayList<Long> cc = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> range = new ArrayList<>();

    // break point is a method that returns list values, it was converted to
    // string because of some concatenations and would be converted back to long here
    for (String ari1 : Breakpoint()) {
        cc.add(Long.valueOf(ari1));
    }

    // the size of the List is huge about 1 trillion entries at the minimum
    long hy = cc.size() - 1;

    for (long k = 0; k < hy; k++) {
        futureTasks.add(Main.exeService.submit(new CompartmentalizationTask(cc, k)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < futureTasks.size(); i++) {
        futureTasks.get(i).get();
    }
    exeService.shutdown();
}

public static void compartmentalize(ArrayList<Long> cc, long index)
{
    long t1 = (long) cc.get((int) index);
    long t2 = (long) cc.get((int) (index + 1));

    // My main question: I am trying to iterate the entire list in a dynamic way
    // which would exclude repeated endpoints on each iteration.

    range = LongStream.rangeClosed(t1 + 1, t2)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (long i : range) {
        // Hard is another method call on the iteration
        // complexcalc is a method as well

        essir2 = complexcalc((int) i, (int) Hard(i));
        essir3 += essir2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have implemented this problem in so many other ways, either with arrays as you can see tt4() is the forth version, so I agree that I would shave off some overhead execution time using an array here, but I have a method that does that exactly, my focus is really on how to make the compiler run the array size in compartments in a kind of parallel way , and the reason for long is that when integers get too large it starts giving calculation errors

Comment: For some reason I was thinking of `double` when I was giving that last suggestion, I've removed it as it was not correct.

Comment: @OlaB I've edited my answer to include an answer to what I believe you're actually looking for. As the disclaimer in the answer states, I am not too familiar with this concept but this should give you a good place to continue your research on how to further optimize your code. I believe multi-threading is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks alot, I have implemented "ForkJoinPool"  alongside the method in the codes, but from what I'm realizing libraries "alone" cant be the answer, it has to be a logic which I need to use. A logic based on thinking is what i'm saying. Thanks

Comment: @OlaB What do you mean with *"libraries can't be the answer"*? I have not used any external libraries only those provided by Java JDK.

Comment: Yes i know, i'm saying in addition to the services I'm looking for a logic as well.

Comment: @OlaB Your question was how to *"enhance the performance of my algorithm by splitting the range of my loop iterations over a large array list"*. I believe using multiple threads to process each loop cycle will dramatically improve your algorithm. Since each loop cycle will be ran in parallel instead of waiting for the last one to finish.

Comment: @OlaB Hm, I do believe this provides you with logic as well: run the tasks in parallel rather then one after another blocking future loop cycles until the last ones have completed. But what you're asking now is how to improve your execution time without using multiple threads, correct?

Comment: yes multiple threads would certainly help as you have suggested, but I am also looking for a logic of using sub-intervals over an interval alongside, I would try out the service you recommended and see how much better it now and come back here later, I would up vote but I might still be looking more for the interval answer, more like how a sieve was used mathematically for interval looping with squares/roots idk if you understand me. But thanks, let me try out the service now

Comment: believe it or not it was about the same run time: 34 seconds run time for 10million entries with your edit; Array List and without the edit: 34 seconds run time seconds for 10 million entries, with an Array instead of List 29 seconds for 10million entries with/without your edit; your edit being the service you had suggested, I told you I had tried the Fork Join class as well and it was the same thing, I think the focus here is really on the magnitude .

Comment: If I could split the List/Array into a size of 10 million per concurrent run, that would be 29 secs per each iteration at the current time estimate, and if i used the logic I'm looking for it would be roughly 290 secs for 100 million entries as they would be parallel over the 100 million entries, each 10 million entries independent of the next 10 million entries but automated. But if I were to directly loop over 100 million entries this way as I have it now, it would take much more than 4 minutes/290 secs, I don't know if you understand clearer now my intent.

Comment: @Mathew Lastly I cant directly use the sizes I need because i get OOM on parallel limit operation on such limits. I have other methods besides Lists, and arrays I implemented, its all just time considerations. I thought I could speed things up this way.